# Selenium Jenkins Linux TestNG - how to run?

Tags: java, linux, selenium, jenkins, testng

Right now I'm running Jenkins on Windows via command line, so:

1. I have xml files generated in Eclipse (by `TestNG -> Convert to TestNG`)
2. I have `run.bat` file with

   ```
   java -cp bin;libs/* org.testng.TestNG c.xml
   java -cp bin;libs/* org.testng.TestNG json.xml
   ```
3. I've created new project in Jenkins to run this bat file

This solution is working for me, but I want to run test on Linux, and I need to direction how to do this the right way.

Comment: why not maven project and create a maven job in jenkins and execute a goal?

Comment: OK, I will try with Maven, if this is a better way

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the same. Java is the same on Linux - at least, from running TestNg tests perspective

Comment: Just notice that the classpath separator on Linux is `:` and not `;` (for the `run.sh`).